# Adding a button for each group in an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I'm using an `ExpandableListView` with group items and child items generated from data I get. Now I need a button on the bottom of each generated group with an onClickListener which invokes a function that has to know what group the button is affiliated to.

Adding it to my `list_group.xml` layout file will add the button on the *Sample Data Title*-Header and adding it to my `list_item.xml` will add it to every single *Sample data*-TextView element.

It's my first project using Android Studio and I got stuck trying to fix the problem.

**Here is a screenshot of [how the list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1r7k.jpg)**

 I'm trying to add the button where *button* item is.

***This is my function to fill the list with data:***

```
private void prepareListData(ccyPair[] ccyPairs) {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            int counter = 0;
            // Adding child data
            for (ccyPair p : ccyPairs){
                listDataHeader.add("Sample Data Title");
                List<String> tempExpInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("Sample data");
                tempExpInfo.add("BUTTON");
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), tempExpInfo);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

***list_group.xml file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorExpandableList">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorExpandableList"
        android:textColor="#2282c1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***list_item.xml file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorExpandableList"><![CDATA[
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    ]]>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorExpandableList"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

***And the ExpandableListAdapter***

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getChildView() method is where you wanna look

**First option:**

In the getChildView() method you have to distinguish which view you want to inflate.

```
if(isLastChild){
    convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_with_button, null);
} else {
    convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}
```

For the last child you create a list_item_with_button.xml which contains a button component. You can then check the isLastChild boolean flag to inflate this new layout to get the button at the last position.

**Second option:** You can edit the existing list_item.xml and add a button to it, which you show at the last position by

```
View button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
if(isLastChild){
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option did work but also messed up alot. But the second option does the job with no problems!